Android ContentResolver duplicate file name is increased instead of appending
I'm using Android ContentResolver to save JPG images whose file name has the form of a serial number made up by digits only (like 34123450.jpg). MIME type used is image/jpg and the relative path is a custom directory inside DCIM.
When saving multiple photos for the same serial number, the ContentResolver has a different beaviour when the length of the file name is exactly 8 digits long. For example:

0123456789.jpg copies are saved as you'd expect, 0123456789 (1).jpg, 0123456789 (2).jpg ...
01234567.jpg is instead increased by 1, like 01234568.jpg, 01234569.jpg, 01234570.jpg and so on

I tested if the same behaviour would happen with 5, 6 or 9+ digit long names, but it behaves normally, suggesing that it may have something to do with 8-digit names resembling a date in yyymmdd format.
